# MySQL function returning multiple rows, need 1 row

Tags: mysql, function

```
SELECT count(*)
from media
where STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2014', '-', `datum`), '%Y-%e-%b') = givendate AND medium_cat like p_media AND `positief_negatief` like p_sentiment
into results;
```

This is the main code of the function, it checks if there is a media record in media that has the same date as the given date.
It returns 61 rows with 1 as result (there are 61 rows in media, and the result should be 1), so it needs to be 1 row with 1 as result.

The main problem is that this function runs 10 times on a table with 100000 rows, so it takes about 120 seconds to complete. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've tried, that doesn't work. Maybe I'm using it wrong?

Comment: `LIMITS` ? have used

Comment: Nope doesn't work either, it just changes the result to the number I'm limiting to.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) into results
from media
where STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2014', '-', `datum`), '%Y-%e-%b') = givendate AND medium_cat like p_media AND `positief_negatief` like p_sentiment
;
```

Just try above code.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Please provide O/P for this qeury `SELECT count(*)
from media
where STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2014', '-', `datum`), '%Y-%e-%b') = givendate AND medium_cat like p_media AND positief_negatief  like p_sentiment`

Comment: O/P? Sorry I don't have much experience.

Comment: O/P means output

Comment: Yeah I've tried it outside of the function, and then it works fine and returns one row. That's the weird thing.

Comment: Not possible.
And one more thing ,if you just want to get count through that function then there is no need to create function you can directly execute this query using variable `@count_out` and it will provide you final output.

Comment: Yeah that's really what happened, with the same data and code it returns 1 row out of the function and 61 inside. I need the function because it is called in a view.